How to properly pass destinations to a TVFocusGuideView in React Native
I'm having trouble with focus redirection using TVFocusGuideView in React Native for a TV App I'm developing. Basically I have a sidebar in my application, and when the user views content, they are navigated to a separate route (using react-navigation). When they back out of the content-player, they are taken back to the home screen, which consists of two components: The sidebar and content page.
I have the sidebar on the left, so it comes before the content page in JSX, like so:
<TVFocusGuideView
      trapFocusUp={true}
      trapFocusDown={true}
      style={styles.container}
      destinations={destinations}>
      <SideBar
        tabInfo={tabInfo}
        selectedKey={selectedKey}
        onIconPressed={onIconPressed}
        isExpanded={isExpanded}
        setIsExpanded={setIsExpanded}
      />
      <Animated.View style={contentAnimationStyle} ref={ref}>
        <TVFocusGuideView
          autoFocus={true}
          trapFocusDown={true}
          trapFocusRight={true}
          trapFocusUp={true}
          style={styles.fullTVFocusGuide}>
          {content}
        </TVFocusGuideView>
      </Animated.View>
    </TVFocusGuideView>

Currently, the SideBar is what is receiving focus when I navigate back to it from the content player. But I want the {content} to be focused instead.
The content itself is just rendered from what the current state of my NavigationBuilder is (e.g. Home, User Profile, etc.) - here's the code for that:
const { state, descriptors, navigation, NavigationContent } = useNavigationBuilder<
    TabNavigationState<ParamListBase>,
    TabRouterOptions,
    TabActionHelpers<ParamListBase>,
    BottomTabNavigationOptions,
    BottomTabNavigationEventMap
  >(TabRouter, {
    id,
    initialRouteName,
    backBehavior,
    children,
    screenListeners,
    screenOptions,
    defaultScreenOptions,
  });

  const content = useMemo(() => {
    return state.routes.map((route, i) => {
      return (
        <View
          key={route.key}
          style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, { display: i === state.index ? 'flex' : 'none' }]}>
          {descriptors[route.key].render()}
        </View>
      );
    });
  }, [descriptors, state.index, state.routes]);

I thought redirecting focus to the outer Animated.View that's wrapping the content would be sufficient, and I'm trying to do so using the destinations prop on the outermost TVFocusGuideView that wraps both the SideBar and the Animated.View content. From what I thought, it should be as simple as attaching a ref to a child component within the TVFocusGuideView, then setting the destinations array to just be TVFocusGuideView destinations={[ref.current]}, but that doesn't seem to do anything.
I thought maybe the ref wasn't being set properly, and when jumping into the definition of TVFocusGuideView I saw it also could accept a node handle, so I figured I could test setting destinations to be an array of the node handles like so:
const ref = useRef<Animated.View>(null);
  const [destinations, setDestinations] = useState<number[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Ensure destinations are updated once the ref is set
    if (ref.current) {
      const nodeHandle = findNodeHandle(ref.current);
      if (nodeHandle) {
        setDestinations([nodeHandle]);
      }
    }
  }, [ref]);

But even when I pass this in as TVFocusGuideView destinations={destinations}, it still doesn't do anything. I'm just confused, am I using this wrong?
I thought perhaps it's the fact that it's a View ref, and replaced the View with just a TouchableOpacity, but that didn't work either.
To summarize, I've tried:

Passing in a ref to the Animated.View , setting that ref as destinations=[ref.current] for the outermost TVFocusGuideView
Removing the content and just having a blank View with a  and linking that to the outermost TVFocusGuideViews destinations=[ref.current] just to see if the content itself was messing with the destinations prop.
Passing in the node's numeric handle via a combination of useState, useEffect, and findNodeHandle

All has resulted in no change though (the SideBar is still focused first)

I recommend adding hasTVPreferredFocus to the TVFocusGuideView wrapping the content.

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.
